# Как запустить приложение .exe в скрытом режиме, через WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день.
Моя задача выглядит следующим образом: у меня есть программа в exe формате, есть программа на WPF открытая в full screen режиме. С помощью библиотеки "TestStack-White", я запускают .exe приложение, и кликаю по кнопкам. В это время моё окно WPF перекрывается приложением .exe. 
Сам вопрос: каким образом можно реализовать режим открытия .ехе программы с WPF, чтобы во время работы .exe программы окно WPF не перекрывались(запуск  .exe в скрытом режиме например, обычный запуск с параметрами черезsystem.diagnostics.process не подходит, так как мне нужно управлять программо(кликать по определённым кнопками(грубое пояснение) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так, чтобы ваша WPF программа была всегда сверху над любой другой открытой программой.

Подпишитесь на событие `Deactivated` у главного окна вашей программы

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Deactivated += MainWindow_Deactivated;
}
```

В обработчике события должно быть так

```
private void MainWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Topmost = true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это работает!

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно это поможет:

Установка `Visibility = Hidden` и установка `ShowInTaskbar` в значение `false`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Ссылка на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690848/completely-hide-wpf-window-on-startup)